# What am I missing to have this appear in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, html5-video, video.js

I have several video-js player code on a web page like this:

```
<video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="140" height="120"
controls poster="/1video/countdown.jpg" data-setup='{}'>
<source src="/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

And this in the header:

```
 <link href="/video-js-4.12.5/video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="/video-js-4.12.5/video-js/video.js"></script>
 <script>videojs.options.flash.swf = "/video-js-4.12.5/video-js/video-js.swf"</script>
```

What do I need to add so the players appear in IE8? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The `<video />` element isn't supported by IE8 - http://caniuse.com/#feat=video

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Internet Explorer 8 does not support the `<video/>` tag that you are using.

[Source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video)

**Update**

video.js should fall back to Flash when loaded in a browser that does not support HTML5 video (e.g. IE 8). There could be several reasons why yours is not working:

1. [Ensure that poster image is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912082/videojs-wont-play-in-ie8-but-plays-in-firefox-chrome-and-safari)
2. [Use a self hosted version of video.js rather than the CDN. Then ensure that your path to video-js.swf is accurate within the JS file](http://www.twistermc.com/38472/fix-video-js-flash-fallback/)
3. [Ensure that your flash plugin is up-to-date](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/981-video-will-not-play-on-ie8)

No. 2 might be most pertinent to your issue. I see that in your header you attempt to change an option. Perhaps try removing that and just ensure that the file path in video.js is accurate (open the JS file and search for video-js.swf).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that IE8 doesn't support the <video> tag, but I believe the video-js somehow works with IE8. Am I missing some code from video-js so that it will work with IE8?

Comment: @ChrisJames did any of this help you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: I believe I have the self-hosted version. My poster image looks like this: poster="http://www...com/video/countdown.jpg" My path to the swf file is this: <script>videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://www....com/video-js-4.12.5/video-js/video-js.swf"</script> Can you clarify what is meant by flash plug-in? Is this file the flash plug-in: /video-js/video-js.swf or is it something else? Do I need this also: https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf  Any additional replies will be appreciated.

Comment: @ChrisJames Rather than specify the path to your video-js.swf file in a script tag in your header, you should check the video-js file directly. Within that file you will find a line that specifies where that video-js.swf file is located. The link under No 2 in my answer talks about this solution.

Comment: Thanks again. I have opened up the file /video-js/video.js. And when I search for "swf" the only line I see is: "GENERATED_CDN_VSN" !== t.ic && (videojs.options.flash.swf = t.vd + "vjs.zencdn.net/" + t.ic + "/video-js.swf");   I'm not sure what to do next. Any additional help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ChrisJames ok, locate the .swf file and change that code to `video.js.options.flash.swf={{path to that .swf file}}`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to enlighten me, much appreciated. I changed that line to: "GENERATED_CDN_VSN"!==t.ic&&(video.js.options.flash.swf={{http://www....com/video-js-4.12.5/video-js/video-js.swf file}}"); (with the domain name included of course), uploaded that video.js file back into the vide-js folder, cleared my cache, and yet still see nothing in IE8. Does GENERATED_CDN mean I have the CDN version? Because, I'm self-hosted. Any additional guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for all of your replies